# Java ZipInputStream closes after reading ZipEntry of image

Tags: java, image, unzip

We are trying to modify one of the XML files in 2007 MS Excel. For this, the xlsx file is being unzipped using Java's ZipInputStream and then copied to a new Zip file using ZipOutputStream. The code snippets are as below :

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\_132139TRD-GDR_Conversion.xlsx");
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));

        FileOutputStream fos =  new FileOutputStream("C:\\_132139TRD-GDR_Conversion123.xlsx");
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));

        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            System.out.println("Processing Entry : " + entry.getName());
            System.out.println("Processing Entry Size : " + entry.getSize());
            System.out.println("Entry Available : " + zis.available());

        if(entry.getName().equals(ZIP_ENTRY_WOOKBOOK_XML)){
          //Process XML
        }

        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(entry.getName());
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            if(entry.getName().equals(ZIP_ENTRY_WOOKBOOK_XML)){
                    zos.write(XML.getBytes());
            }else{
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    stream.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                tempBuffer = stream.toByteArray();
                zos.write(tempBuffer);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();               
        }
        zos.close();
        fos.close();
        zis.close();
        fis.close();
```

In this snippet, after we encounter a JPEG file, the "entry = zis.getNextEntry()" returns null. We are not able to read the next ZipEntry - which leads to an incomplete Excel. The output for a sample Excel file is as below :

```
Start Date Mon Dec 06 15:33:33 IST 2010
Processing Entry : xl/media/Logo2005_JPM_A_Black_170x50.jpeg
Processing Entry Size : -1
Entry Available : 1
End Date Mon Dec 06 15:34:58 IST 2010
```

The ZipInputStream gets closed as soon as the JPEG file is copied. (entryEOF and reachEOF variables both turn true and entry is null after copying the image).

Has anybody faced a similar issue ? Is it a bug that reachEOF also turns true after copying the file ?

Midhun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you read the data for the image from `zis` instead of from `zis.getInputStream(entry)`.

After the copy loop, all data from `zis` will have been read, so you get an EOF.